# How can I remember my dreams?

Tags: sleeping

I do dream in the sleep but the moment I wake up I only remember a very little of thing and after some minutes, I don't actually remember any of my dreams. Why is it so? Can someone suggest me how to remember my dreams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a notepad by the bed. As soon as you wake up, write the dream down before it fades.

At first you may only be able to remember key items, but it gets easier the more you do it.

Comment: The important thing is to start writing while you are still in a state of half-sleep. As soon as you begin to wake, grab the notepad and start writing. Do not wait until you are fully awake, as the dreams will fade in proportion to your wakefulness. – Also, do not censor or try to write "beautifully", just jot down whatever comes to your mind as quickly as you can.  – And Rory is right: You get better at remembering your dreams with practice. If you want, you can go so far as to train yourself to remain conscious while you sleep. Search for "lucid dreaming" to learn more about this.

Comment: a voice recorder might be eiaser to use in the dark, plus the vocal tone can refresh memory.

Comment: that may work for some people - I found it woke me up too much, and disturbed my partner...

Answer (score -1):

To remember your dreams, the minute you wake up, get out of bed and start doing whatever you do first thing in the morning.

There's something about laying in bed half awake, or hitting the snooze alarm, that makes the dreams fade.  I can't explain it but this makes a difference.

Comment: When I think about my average weekday morning, this sounds like a recipe to *certainly* forget about the dream.